# Evaluating the position operator in momentum space

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, momentum, fourier-transform

I'm a bit lost with the following derivation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\left\langle p^{\prime}|x| p^{\prime \prime}\right\rangle & =\int\left\langle p^{\prime}|x| x^{\prime}\right\rangle\left\langle x^{\prime} \mid p^{\prime \prime}\right\rangle d x^{\prime}=\int x^{\prime}\left\langle p^{\prime} \mid x^{\prime}\right\rangle\left\langle x^{\prime} \mid p^{\prime \prime}\right\rangle d x^{\prime} \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \pi \hbar} \int x^{\prime} \exp \left[-i \frac{\left(p^{\prime}-p^{\prime \prime}\right) \cdot x^{\prime}}{\hbar}\right] d x^{\prime} \\
&=i \frac{\partial}{\partial p^{\prime}} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \exp \left[-i \frac{\left(p^{\prime}-p^{\prime \prime}\right) \cdot x^{\prime}}{\hbar}\right] d x^{\prime} \\
& =i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p^{\prime}} \delta\left(p^{\prime}-p^{\prime \prime}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

In specific, how do we get from line 2 to 3 ? I'm confused because $x^{\prime}$ is a scalar value and it's somehow pulled out of the integral and gets transformed into an operator. I think there's also integration by parts, but the appearance of $\frac{\partial}{\partial p^{\prime}}$ in line 3 troubles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get $x'$ by differentiating the exponential with respect to $p'$, the derivative pulls down a factor of $-ix'/\hbar$. This is exactly what the second line is. The following identity has been used
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial p'}\exp \left[-i \frac{\left(p^{\prime}-p^{\prime \prime}\right) \cdot x^{\prime}}{\hbar}\right] = -i\frac{x'}{\hbar}\exp \left[-i \frac{\left(p^{\prime}-p^{\prime \prime}\right) \cdot x^{\prime}}{\hbar}\right]. 
$$
Plug this in the third line and you will get the second line.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial p} e^{ipx} = i x e^{ipx}
$$

it's just making this substitution (in reverse so to speak) on the integrand.